# Integrate Android with Halcon

Tags: android, android-ndk

I want integrate android NDK with Halcon.

I try use the libs ( headers files) to evoke Halcon methods.

For example:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include "com_example_joseubuntu_integrationhalcon_MainActivity.h"
#  include "HALCONCpp/HalconCpp.h"
#  include "HALCONCpp/HDevThread.h"

using namespace HalconCpp;

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_joseubuntu_integrationhalcon_MainActivity_testFunction(JNIEnv * env, jobject obj)
{

    HTuple  hv_BarCodeHandle;

    HTuple  hv_DecodedDataStrings;

    HObject  ho_Image,ho_SymbolRegions;

    CreateBarCodeModel(HTuple(), HTuple(), &hv_BarCodeHandle);

    SetBarCodeParam(hv_BarCodeHandle, "stop_after_result_num", 1);

    ReadImage(&ho_Image, "/res/drawable/codebar");

    FindBarCode(ho_Image, &ho_SymbolRegions, hv_BarCodeHandle, "EAN-13", &hv_DecodedDataStrings);

    WriteImage(ho_SymbolRegions, "png", "0xffff00", "Teste.png");

}
```

Is a simple example to read barCodes, i don't know if this work, because i have this errors:

```
Error:error: undefined reference to 'HalconCpp::HTuple::~HTuple()'
Error:error: undefined reference to 'HalconCpp::HTuple::HTuple(char const*)'
Error:error: undefined reference to 'HalconCpp::HTuple::HTuple()'
Error:error: undefined reference to 'HalconCpp::HTuple::~HTuple()'
Error:error: undefined reference to 'HalconCpp::HObjectBase::HObjectBase()'
Error:error: undefined reference to 'HalconCpp::CreateBarCodeModel(HalconCpp::HTuple const&, HalconCpp::HTuple const&, HalconCpp::HTuple*)'
Error:error: undefined reference to 'HalconCpp::HTuple::HTuple()'
Error:error: undefined reference to 'HalconCpp::HTuple::~HTuple()'
Error:error: undefined reference to 'HalconCpp::SetBarCodeParam(HalconCpp::HTuple const&, HalconCpp::HTuple const&, HalconCpp::HTuple const&)'
Error:error: undefined reference to 'HalconCpp::HObjectBase::HObjectBase()'
Error:error: undefined reference to 'HalconCpp::HTuple::HTuple(int)'
Error:error: undefined reference to 'HalconCpp::HTuple::HTuple()'
Error:error: undefined reference to 'HalconCpp::HTuple::HTuple()'
Error:error: undefined reference to 'HalconCpp::HTuple::~HTuple()'
Error:error: undefined reference to 'HalconCpp::HTuple::HTuple(char const*)'
Error:error: undefined reference to 'HalconCpp::ReadImage(HalconCpp::HObject*, HalconCpp::HTuple const&)'
Error:error: undefined reference to 'HalconCpp::HTuple::HTuple(char const*)'
Error:error: undefined reference to 'HalconCpp::FindBarCode(HalconCpp::HObject const&, HalconCpp::HObject*, HalconCpp::HTuple const&, HalconCpp::HTuple const&, HalconCpp::HTuple*)'
Error:error: undefined reference to 'HalconCpp::HTuple::HTuple(char const*)'
Error:error: undefined reference to 'HalconCpp::WriteImage(HalconCpp::HObject const&, HalconCpp::HTuple const&, HalconCpp::HTuple const&, HalconCpp::HTuple const&)'
Error:error: undefined reference to 'HalconCpp::HObjectBase::~HObjectBase()'
Error:error: undefined reference to 'HalconCpp::HObjectBase::~HObjectBase()'
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the halcon library for android?

If the library you used is not for android, it cannot work.

If you have the library for android, you should import the so library in the `Android.mk` like this:

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := libhalcon

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := lib/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libhalcon.so

include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := libhalconcpp

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := lib/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/libhalconcpp.so

include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```